# Xcode 6.1.1 - Developer ID is not on any development teams, when it IS

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-id

We had to change our development ID (apple ID) due to a change in email addresses.
We changed the email in the dev portal and via Apple ID.
Everything seemed fine - we could log into the portal and iTunes Connect and see our apps/certificates etc etc for the iOS dev team.

Tried to build our app, however, and Xcode seems to have other ideas, claiming that our (now new) Apple ID is not part of a development team!

The below are the steps we've been using to try to resolve the problem, to no avail:

1. Removed all certificates from keychain
2. Also removed any saved login-passwords from keychain
3. Went to Apple Member Centre, entered with new email address now being used for development.
4. Navigate to iOS Dev Centre
5. Navigate to Certificates
6. Downloaded Development and Distribution certificates (note that we did create brand new certificates)
7. Moved certificates from 6 into Keychain log-in
8. Download Provisioning profile (not sure why - can't seem to do anything with it since it looks like Xcode manages this itself)
9. Opened Xcode, go to Prefs > Accounts
10. Added account using new Apple ID
11. Account is added, however, it shows under the ID "xxxx@xxx.com is not on any development teams"

We have repeated the above steps (including reboot of mac) over and over again, with no changes.  This is our development account (i can log into dev centre and iTunes connect fine and see our apps etc)... but Xcode tells us it isn't ><

Hope someone can shed some light on this, as we're all out of ideas here.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WHY DIDNT WE DO THIS FIRST?!**

A lesson for us for the future.

We're using Unity to develop our app.

All we needed to do to resolve the issue is create a brand new build (we deleted the old one), rather than just do an amend build through unity.

Creating a fresh build resolved this developer ID issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would either contact Apple or **reboot your computer.**

If those don't work, comment here for more help.

Comment: Yes, done both. Have sent two requests to Apple but not response yet. Rebooted twice.

Comment: So, did Apple work something out? I tried every suggestion here but nothing solved this for me yet...

Comment: See below answer from us. We're using Unity and rather than do an append build, we had to do a replace build to resolve it.